# Warning when opening commit message with Neovim

Tags: spell-checking, neovim, git, filetype-git

I've been using Neovim for a few days with no problem, so I decided to switch my git config to use Neovim instead of vim. Here's what I put in my global `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    editor = nvim
```

And here's the warning when I run `git commit` now:

```
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After pressing a key, it works fine, except that it doesn't do spell checking like vim used to do. Here's what I've got in my `.nvimrc` to turn on spell checking in git commit messages.

```
autocmd Filetype gitcommit setlocal spell textwidth=72
```

Comment: This behavior has been reported at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1551 as a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I run `:set spell`, I get:

```
spellfile#LoadFile(): There is no writable spell directory
Shall I create /Users/adamharris/.nvim/spell
(Y)es, [N]o:
```

Select y

```
Cannot find spell file for "en" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it?
(Y)es, [N]o:
```

Select y, and it will download the file.

```
In which directory do you want to write the file:
1. /Users/adamharris/.nvim/spell
[C]ancel, (1):
```

Select 1

```
Do you want me to try to get the .sug file?
This will improve making suggestions for spelling mistakes,
but it uses quite a bit of memory.
[N]o, (Y)es:
```

I selected y, and downloaded the file.

Then spellchecking works just fine!